# How to list Google Drive files by using its JavaScript API in a website?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a search function in a website which it can display corresponding **Google Drive files** when user key in keywords in a text box.

The UI looks similar to following:

[image]

When user input word into the text box, there will be a list of corresponding Google files appear if any.

Of course, there should be an authentication step for the Google account first.

I think it may use Google Drive API for JavaScript and AJAX skills, but I am not sure how to implement that?

Reference: [Google Drive APIs: JavaScript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js)

Does someone can give me any suggestions?
Thank you very much!!

Comment: You can [search or filter](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) files with the [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) method of the Drive API. These methods accept the `q` parameter which is a search query combining one or more search clauses. Each search clause is made up of three parts: Field, Operator and Value. Combine clauses with the conjunctions `and` or `or`, and negate the query with `not`. For your case, you can use the `contains` operator which performs prefix matching for a `name`.

Comment: Thank @abielita, could you please paste sample code? I wonder how it is, thanks a lot!!